# Non-blocking functional methods with Reactive Mongo and Web client

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I have a micro service which reads objects from a database using a `ReactiveMongoRepository` interface.

The goal is to take each one of those objects and push it to a AWS Lambda function (after converting it to a DTO). If the result of that lambda function is in the 200 range, mark the object as being a success otherwise ignore.

In the old days of a simple Mongo Repository and a RestTemplate this is would be a trivial task. However I'm trying to understand this Reactive deal, and avoid blocking.

Here is the code I've come up with, I know I'm blocking on the `webClient`, but how do I avoid that?

```
@Override
public Flux<Video> index() {
    return videoRepository.findAllByIndexedIsFalse().flatMap(video -> {
        final SearchDTO searchDTO = SearchDTO.builder()
                .name(video.getName())
                .canonicalPath(video.getCanonicalPath())
                .objectID(video.getObjectID())
                .userId(video.getUserId())
                .build();

        // Blocking call
        final HttpStatus httpStatus = webClient.post()
                .uri(URI.create(LAMBDA_ENDPOINT))
                .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(searchDTO)).exchange()
                .block()
                .statusCode();

        if (httpStatus.is2xxSuccessful()) {
            video.setIndexed(true);
        }

        return videoRepository.save(video);
    });
}
```

I'm calling the above from a scheduled task, and I don't really care about that actual result of the index() method, just what happens during.

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000)
public void indexTask() {
    indexService
            .index()
            .log()
            .subscribe();
}
```

I've read a bunch of blog posts etc on the subject but they're all just simple CRUD operations without anything happening in the middle so don't really give me a full picture of how to implement these things.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is actually quite close.
In those cases, you should try and decompose the reactive chain in steps and not hesitate to turn bits into independent methods for clarity.

```
@Override
public Flux<Video> index() {

    Flux<Video> unindexedVideos = videoRepository.findAllByIndexedIsFalse();
    return unindexedVideos.flatMap(video -> {
        final SearchDTO searchDTO = SearchDTO.builder()
                .name(video.getName())
                .canonicalPath(video.getCanonicalPath())
                .objectID(video.getObjectID())
                .userId(video.getUserId())
                .build();

        Mono<ClientResponse> indexedResponse = webClient.post()
            .uri(URI.create(LAMBDA_ENDPOINT))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(searchDTO)).exchange()
            .filter(res -> res.statusCode().is2xxSuccessful());

        return indexedResponse.flatMap(response -> {
            video.setIndexed(true);
            return videoRepository.save(video);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

my approach, maybe a little bit more readable. But I admit I didn't run it so not 100% guarantee that it will work.

```
public Flux<Video> index() {
    return videoRepository.findAll()
        .flatMap(this::callLambda)
        .flatMap(videoRepository::save);
}

private Mono<Video> callLambda(final Video video) {
    SearchDTO searchDTO = new SearchDTO(video);
    return webClient.post()
            .uri(URI.create(LAMBDA_ENDPOINT))
            .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(searchDTO))
            .exchange()
            .map(ClientResponse::statusCode)
            .filter(HttpStatus::is2xxSuccessful)
            .map(t -> {
                video.setIndexed(true);
                return video;
            });
}
```